# Auto_increment jumps randomly in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've created database with prices:

```
CREATE TABLE price(
price_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
full_price INT NULL,
price_m2 INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(price_id)
);
```

When iam adding data to database, id's numbers is jumping randomly, even skipping with no pattern.

```
price_id | full_price | price_m2
         |            |
679         1200000     13043
1958        1200320     10259
1590        939000      9390
1591        939000      9390
383         665000      9236
749         1800000     9000
2085        1646000     8998
474         585000      8685
616         750000      8523
```

What could be wrong with it ?

Comment: First, whether or not the identifiers are in sequence and/or have gaps should ***never*** matter to the function of your applications. They are known as surrogate keys, and their ***only*** function is to uniquely identify a row. If you're using them to infer anything else, you're misusing them. Second, database distribution, concurrent transactions, deletions or rollbacks, etc, can all make a difference. To diagnose the cause we would need to know the exact database configuration ***and*** the exact sequence of events to be able to replicate the scenario.

Comment: Oh, i did a lot of deletions recently. Maybe that is the problem. I will delete old DB and create new then. Thanks for swift answer :)

Comment: You didn't show the query used to produce that result. I guess it is sorting by `price_m2` in descending order. So the primary key values appear to be out of order.